# Java: AWS lambda to SQS queue; How to send mesage to SQS queue with S3 event record directly?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have to create a lambda that will take s3 trigger and do some tasks and also send the s3 record to sqs for further processing after some time. The reason that I need to send to SQS queue through the lambda is because there is already a trigger for a bucket folder and I cannot use 2 triggers in the same bucket folder. There is another lambda that uses this SQS queue which I didnt write so I need to send the whole record in sqs queue.I am quite new to Java with AWS and I dont know how to
I need to send s3 event directly to the SQS queue, how can I send to the message body directly:

```
public String handleRequest(S3Event event, Context context) {
    sendSQSQueue(event.getRecords())
}

void sendSQSQueueToLoadPartitions(List<S3EventNotification.S3EventNotificationRecord> records){
    SendMessageRequest send_msg_request = new SendMessageRequest()
        .withQueueUrl(envVariables.getQueueUrl())
        .withMessageBody(records)
        .withDelaySeconds(1);
    sqsClient.sendMessage(send_msg_request);
}
```

How to pass List<S3EventNotification.S3EventNotificationRecord> into withMessageBody()

The docs state that:
A message can include only XML, JSON, and unformatted text
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sqs/model/SendMessageRequest.html#withMessageBody-java.lang.String-

Sample SQS queue that is processed by another lambda:

```
    {
"Records": [
    {
        "eventVersion": "2.1",
        "eventSource": "aws:s3",
        "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
        "eventTime": "2021-06-04T19:51:57.524Z",
        "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
        "userIdentity": {
            "principalId": "AWS:AR"
        },
        "requestParameters": {
            "sourceIPAddress": ""
        },
        "responseElements": {
            "x-amz-request-id": "",
            "x-amz-id-2": "5T/i"
        },
        "s3": {
            "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0",
            "configurationId": "saqs-2",
            "bucket": {
                "name": "bucketname",
                "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname"
            },
            "object": {
                "key": "tier2/test.txt",
                "size": 5527,
                "eTag": "",
                "sequencer": ""
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

Comment: You should instead configure S3 to publish its notifications on a topic and then have your lambda / queue / anything else subscribed to that topic.

Comment: thats a good solution but requires code changes on both my lambda and another lambda that is receiving sqs queue. Thanks, I will bring this up with my employer but Iif there is a way to convert that event.getRecords() to string format please let me know